# oracle error ORA-24344 on creating trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I am newbie to oracle.
I want to create a trigger to backup table TRIGGER_TEST's rowdata into TABLE TRIGGER_TEST_BK. But showing invalid。

here's the schema and errors：

```
CREATE TABLE "OA_TEST"."TRIGGER_TEST" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "TEXT" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "UPDATE_TIME" DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "OA_TEST"."SYS_C0063741" ON "OA_TEST"."TRIGGER_TEST" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J";


CREATE TABLE "OA_TEST"."TRIGGER_TEST_BK" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TT_ID" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "TEXT" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "UPDATE_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "OA_TEST"."SYS_C0063745" ON "OA_TEST"."TRIGGER_TEST_BK" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "HCIS4J";
```

trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger OA_TEST.TRI_BK_TRIGGER_TEST AFTER update or DELETE on OA_TEST.TRIGGER_TEST
  2  FOR EACH ROW
  3  begin
  4  insert into OA_TEST.TRIGGER_TEST_BK(ID, TT_ID, TYPE, TEXT, UPDATE_TIME) values(sys_guid(), OLD.ID, OLD.TYPE, OLD.TEXT, sysdate)
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

when I show errors;

```
2/1  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

2/129    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

3/4  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
     one of the following:
     begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
     null pragma raise return select update while with
     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
     <a bind variable> << close current delete fetch lock insert
     open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
     pipe
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone Help?

After adding a semicolon after 'insert into ...' statement.

```
create or replace trigger OA_TEST.TRI_BK_TRIGGER_TEST AFTER update or DELETE on OA_TEST.TRIGGER_TEST
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    insert into OA_TEST.TRIGGER_TEST_BK(ID, TT_ID, TYPE, TEXT, UPDATE_TIME) values(sys_guid(), OLD.ID, OLD.TYPE, OLD.TEXT, sysdate);
END;
```

Errors for TRIGGER OA_TEST.TRI_BK_TRIGGER_TEST:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/3  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/116    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

It seems, you are missing a semicolon after your 'insert into ...' statement in the trigger body.

Comment: thanks for answing！but after that errors:    Errors for TRIGGER OA_TEST.TRI_BK_TRIGGER_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/3  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/116  PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: @EmmerichLiang - that's because `OLD` should be `:OLD`.